# Make EventListener only fire once, without removing it - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Okay so I have the following line of code...

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", sHeader);

function sHeader(){
var yPosition = window.pageYOffset;

 if ( yPosition = > 5 ){
 header.className += ' shorter';
 }
}
```

...which enables me to change the styles of my header after scrolling. However, it continues to fire unnecessarily as I scroll further down the page, consequently adding more **"shorter"** to the class attribute for **"header"** in HTML; like this:

```
<header class=" shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter...">
```

I understand using the following code eliminates this...

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", sHeader);

function sHeader(){
var yPosition = window.pageYOffset;

 if ( yPosition = > 5 ){
 header.style.height = "60px";
 }
}
```

...however, I just don't like the look of it in HTML after executing, like this:

```
<header style="height: 60px;">
```

Is there any way, without using jQuery, that I can make the provided eventListener fire only once without having to remove it, since it is required again if the yPosition becomes less than 5px (header reverts back to original styles) and a user then decided to scroll back down the page again in the same session.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe the situation, you don't need to fire the event once. There are few ways to solve your problem.

#### Way 1

Use `.classList.add` instead of `.className +=` to avoid `class="shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter shorter..."`.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", sHeader);

function sHeader() {
    var yPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    if (yPosition >= 5){
        header.classList.add('shorter');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('shorter');
    }
}
```

The `classList` property works in IE ≥ 10, but you can use [a polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/).

#### Way 2

Add a variable which remembers whether the header is shortened and check it in the event listener.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", sHeader);

var isHeaderShorter = false;
function sHeader() {
    var yPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    var shouldBeShorter = yPosition >= 5;

    // Checking whether the header should be changed
    if (shouldBeShorter === isHeaderShorter) {
        return;
    }

    if (shouldBeShorter) {
        header.className += ' shorter'
    } else {
        header.className = header.className.split(' shorter').join('');
    }
    isHeaderShorter = shouldBeShorter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{once: true} triggers event only once

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", sHeader, {once: true});
```

Comment: It has [a poor browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility), e.g. not supported in IE and Safari > 10.

Comment: Yes, it won't support IE